# Liquibase Index "PRIMARY_KEY_xx" belongs to a constraint

Tags: liquibase

I have the following table (let's call it TBL), that I'm trying to remove a primary key from. Underlying DB is H2.

```
<createTable tableName="TBL">
        <column name="ID" type="BIGINT">
            <constraints primaryKey="true" primaryKeyName="TBL_PK"/>
        </column>
        ...
```

Trying to use the following script in a later changeset, I run into the error below.

```
<dropPrimaryKey tableName="TBL" constraintName="TBL_PK" />
```

Error:

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Index "PRIMARY_KEY_xx" belongs to a constraint; SQL statement:
ALTER TABLE TBL DROP PRIMARY KEY [90085-140]
```

Any idea what I am missing?

---

I know that there is `dropIndex`, but I don't know how to target the `PRIMARY_KEY_xx` (to stay generic for later stages).

Comment: I guess that problem is with H2 db. When you create PK it creates some constraint(s). Try to find it with query: `select * from information_schema.constraints  where table_name='TBL' and COLUMN_LIST='ID'`

Comment: That actually was the issue. If you repost it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that problem is with H2 db. When you create PK it creates some constraint(s). 
Try to find it with query:
`select * from information_schema.constraints where table_name='TBL' and column_list='ID'`